# Variable named i386 generated by Matlab Coder

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, mingw, matlab-coder

I'm generating code for a function with several variable-sized arrays. The code needs to be compiled in both linux (with gcc) and windows machines (with MinGW).

To "ensure capacity" in those variables, Matlab creates several counter variables, named `i349`, `i350`, ..., `i386`, ... `i400`. Apparently, the windows compiler doesn't like this. It throws two errors that say :

line x:   `error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant`

line y:   `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

line y+1: `error: lvalue required as increment operand`

These are all solved by manually picking other variable names. While I could use some script to automatically do so, I'd rather avoid it.

**Two questions:**

1. Why does these variable names cause a problem with the compiler?
2. How can I tell Matlab not to generate variables with these names?

Comment: I'm guessing that token is reserved by the MinGW compiler, probably relating to [the architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does these variable names cause a problem with the compiler?

These are predefined macros by the compiler. It's nonstandard behavior, but this is used for backwards compatibility in determining what system the code is being compiled for.

> How can I tell Matlab not to generate variables with these names?

You don't want to. Instead, pass a `-std=c...` option to the compiler to have it act in standard-compliant mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a name collision that isn't fixable with compiler flags you can use the `ReservedNameArray` [config setting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/coder.codeconfig.html#d118e54169) with MATLAB Coder:

```matlab
cfg = coder.config('lib');
cfg.ReservedNameArray = 'Name1;Name2';

codegen foo.m -config cfg
```

That will cause Coder to mangle identifiers to not collide with the provided names.